# PHP - MySQL Find word from input field in table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I've been searching for a couple of hours trying to figure this out:

- person types his username in a text field and hits submit, then php checks if the username is in the database(in the table username). What method do i use? or what statement. Because this is really confusing me.

my database is named `arcforum` table is named `afusers` the rows are filled with usernames and what not.

**Visual reference:** [image]

**I tried using:**

```
SELECT username FROM afusers WHERE username LIKE 'DarkEyeDragon';
```

But this returns nothing.

PS: I'm not asking for the completely filled in code(although always welcome). Just a method I can use to do this. Or a simular question.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qUAXt.png Proof table/database is not empty
Code:

```
include_once 'psl-config.php';
$mysqli = new mysqli(HOST, USER, PASSWORD, DATABASE);
if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    header("Location: ../error.php?err=Unable to connect to MySQL");
    exit();
}
```

The next part just prints out every row in the table. Just to make sure everything is working as intended.

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
// output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "id: " . $row["id"]. "| Name: " . $row["username"]. "<br>email: " .     $row["email"]. "<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
exit();
```

after that i'm not entirly sure how I would utilise the code to check if the words are the same.

Comment: Are you sure that the table in question holds any data?

Comment: in theory that query should work, can you show the full php code. The broader question is answered in may thousands of tutorial on the net, and off topic for Stack Overflow

Comment: added more information @Dagon

Comment: how about the code for the actual query

Answer (score -1):

```
$mysqli->query('select * from afusers where username = someusername')
```

You can verify the row quantity with `$mysqli->num_rows`

And then you can fetch your data like this:

```
$user = mysqli_fetch_object($mysqli)
```

That will give you the desired user if the username is unique.

Of course you could use a variable for the username like:

```
 $mysqli->query('select * from afusers where username ="' . $username . '"')
```

Comment: Thanks this was what i was looking for

Comment: Glad it helped you. You can access all of this through the manual though: [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php). Just need a little search.